# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'field' (discord.py, embed)

Tags: python, discord.py, ctx

When I start my Discord Bot it gives me the error:

```
    Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jaron\Documents\PBot_rewrite\bot-env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jaron\Documents\PyBot_rewrite\bot.py", line 81, in stats
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{bot.user.name} Stats', description='\uFEFF', color=ctx.author.colour, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'field'
```

if I run this Code snippet:

```
    @bot.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    """
    A useful command that displays bot statistics.
    """
    pythonVersion = platform.python_version()
    dpyVersion = discord.__version__
    serverCount = len(bot.guilds)
    memberCount = len(set(bot.get_all_members()))

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{bot.user.name} Stats', description='\uFEFF', color=ctx.author.colour,
                          timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

    embed.add_field(name='Bot Version:', value=bot.version)
    embed.add_field(name='<:python:818814561456095233> Python Version:', value=pythonVersion)
    embed.add_field(name='<:discordpy:818474661410766899> discord.py Version:', value=dpyVersion)
    embed.add_field(name='Total Guilds:', value=serverCount)
    embed.add_field(name='Total Members:', value=memberCount)
    embed.add_field(name='Bot Developer:', value='<@751092600890458203>')

    embed.set_author(name=bot.user.name, icon_url=bot.user.avatar_url)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If you need more information just ask :)

Stay safe,
Pukima

Comment: Have you tried to input manual `values` to check if something with your definition is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean Dominik? And how? (I am new to discord.py :()

Comment: For example replace `value=pythonVersion` with `"Test"` to check if something is wrong with your code. I would also consider to dissolve the clamp into `embed.title = ...`, `embed.description = ...` etc.

Comment: Now it says `embed.add_field(name='Bot Version:', value=bot.version)
TypeError: add_field() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: Try `self.bot.version`. You should take a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or some tutorials first if you are already struggling at this.

Comment: Bu then it says `embed.add_field(name='Bot Version:', value=self.bot.version)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined`. Also I followed a tutorial but ig it is outdated

Comment: its simply „bot” not „self.bot”

Comment: Lukasz it is not just bot then it throws a error again

Comment: How did you define `bot`?

Comment: Side notes: first of all, the [tag:ctx] tag is not related to this question. Second, there is no need to use a zero-width non-breaking space in the embed description; in your case, you can omit the `description` argument entirely.

Answer (score 0):

`field` does not seem to be the name of a parameter anywhere in the discord.py source code, let alone a parameter to an `__init__` method of a class. I think your issue is that wherever you got `discord.Embed` from is not the real, unmodified discord.py library.